# ARC releases my object before completion handler block is invoked

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, block

I'm wrapping an `UIAlertView` inside a regular `NSObject` to allow completion handler blocks instead of the delegate pattern.

The problem is that I allocate a local instance of my object, that internally creates an `UIAlertView` and assigns its delegate to the object itself. When the alert is shown and the user taps a button, the apps crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because ARC has released my object and the delegate of the alert is **that** object.

How could I handle this situation? I saw that a solution is to qualify the local variable with  `__block` and use the object itself inside the completion block, but that doesn't work.

By the way, if I subclass 'UIalertView' instead of wrapping it, it works, but documentation says that alert subclassing is not recommended, so I prefer to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate your object with the alert view like so:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

...

- (void)showAlertView
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithWhatever:...];        
    objc_setAssociatedObject(alertView, _cmd, self, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    [alertView show];
}
```

That will retain your object, and then release it again when the alertView is dealloced.  Your object mustn't retain the alertView, or you'll have a retain cycle.